# Can't reach ActiveMQ Port on Docker from my host

Tags: docker

I have a docker Image base on Tomcat 7. My web application start a instance of ActiveMQ.
To build the container I add the following configuration
docker run .... -p 61616:61616 ...

I can see the configuration on Docker Inspect command:

```
        "Ports": {
            "5005/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8091"
                }
            ],
            "61616/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "61616"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8090"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Inside the container if I run:

telnet localhost 61616

i can connect to ActiveMQ instance:

```
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
▒ActiveMQTcpNoDelayEnabledSizePrefixDisabled    CacheSizeStackTraceEnabled
                                                                          CacheEnabledTightEncodingEnabledMaxInactivityDurationu0 MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay'
```

From my host I can't:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I look for the port with netstat and is avaliable:

netstat -nao

```
tcp6       0      0 :::61616                :::*                    LISTEN      26503/docker-proxy   off (0.00/0/0)    
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      26511/docker-proxy   off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      26519/docker-proxy   off (0.00/0/0)
```

If I try to telnet to the other port, I can connect.
What I'm missing?

Comment: At least there is no issue with docker or connection to Tomcat, because telnet successfully connects on a network layer to the container. The issue might be on Tomcat application side, some logs might be helpful.

Comment: I think the problem is because only tcp6 is bind. And ActiveMQ it's only listening on tcp4.
On tomcat logs I don't have anything, only the startup lines.
What should I search on logs?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem configuring activeMQ networks with ip **0.0.0.0** Normally the ip was 127.0.0.1 and without dockerizing it, this worked. But inside the docker it didn't

This is my spring jms config (which uses activeMQ)

```
<amq:broker brokerName="${local.broker.name}" id="broker" persistent="false" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true" enableStatistics="false" useLoggingForShutdownErrors="true">
<amq:transportConnectors>
<amq:transportConnector uri="nio://${local.broker.ip}:${local.broker.port}?jms.useAsyncSend=true?jms.useCompression=true" disableAsyncDispatch="false" />
<amq:transportConnectors>
<amq:broker>
```

the application.properties was

```
local.broker.name=broker
local.broker.ip=127.0.0.1
local.broker.port=61617
```

changed it with

```
local.broker.name=broker
local.broker.ip=0.0.0.0
local.broker.port=61617
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had both a ActiveMQ server (embedded, with a TransportConnector to localhost), and a Jetty server, inside the same JVM. The HTTP calls went through fine "from outside" (i.e. the host), but not TCP connections to ActiveMQ. Totally stumped me. Thanks for the solution.